# Can you use pixels in an SVG gradient tag?

Tags: svg, linear-gradients

Here's an SVG gradient specification:

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
```

But instead of percentages (of the rect you're colouring in), is there a way that you can use pixel points that are relative to the entire SVG tag. Like this (for an SVG tag that's 250px in height):

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="250">
```

Comment: I'll add that the issue is only really apparent when you have a large rect and a small rect side-by-side. Both rects will show the entire gradient - but I'd prefer to have it the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the answer: add a *gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"* attribute to the gradient tag

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot when building a line chart with d3.js.

Comment: D3 is a monster at first glance, but once you get used to it, you never want to go back. We have tons of non-aligned time-based data that requires lazyloading, free panning, zooming and live updating. After testing many many higher lever libraries it turned out the best way was to jump into that cold water and learn D3, now I have *exactly* what I needed. But thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at RGraph nevertheless.

Comment: could you comment on its usage (or atleast post an example)